# Blazor Webassembly BlazorDateRangePicker component only works after refreshing page

Tags: datepicker, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Im using BlazorDateRangePicker nugget, followed their instructions here:
https://blazordaterangepicker.azurewebsites.net/

1- Installed the nugget package

2- Added to index.html :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="_content/BlazorDateRangePicker/daterangepicker.min.css" />
```

3- Added to  end:

```
<script src="_content/BlazorDateRangePicker/clickAndPositionHandler.js"></script>
```

4- used this on the page:

```
@using BlazorDateRangePicker

<DateRangePicker />
```

When I click the component throws a exception saying:

> Unhandled exception rendering component: Could not find 'clickAndPositionHandler.addClickOutsideEvent' ('clickAndPositionHandler' was undefined).

After I refresh the page it works normal...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after a few hours changing the place of the scrip inside the Body in index.html, installing and removing the nugget package and searching the web...

I went to the page were I was using the component DateRangePicker, grabbed the using:

```
@using BlazorDateRangePicker
```

it was on top, above all other usings and I moved it to the bottom and then just worked!

Comment: That sounds like a bug. Or it should at least result in an error message. Could you please report this to Microsoft?